# Update customer table with invoices data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

`Customers` (custid, tot_sales, tot_profits)

`Invoices` (custid, sales, profits)

Invoices can have one to many invoices for the same customer.

I'm trying to calculate total sales and profits from invoices and save it in customers.

Here is where I am:

```
select custid, sum(revenus), sum(profits)
from invoices
group by cust
```

It gives me back:

```
CustId    Revenus     Profits
1         1000        200
2         2000        300
```

So far so good.

What I don't now is how to push the data back into customers within the same statement. I was thinking

```
udpate customers
    set tot_revenus, tot_profits 
    select custid, sum(revenus), sum(profits)
    from invoices
    group by cust
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `update with join` :

```
UPDATE Customers c
INNER JOIN (SELECT custId,sum(revenus) as sum_rev,sum(profits) as sum_prof
            FROM Invoices
            GROUP BY custId) i
 ON(c.custId = i.custId)
SET c.tot_sales = i.sum_rev,
    c.tot_profits = i.sum_prof
```

This will basically update `customers` table according to the `derived` table created (containing the sum for each customer).